# Item information missing from order details view

Tags: expresso-store, orders

I've just updated to Store 2.0.5 and have noticed that item information is missing from the order details admin screen - see image.

Item information is shown as expected in my order invoice template, using the `{exp:store:orders}` tag, however it's missing from the admin screen, exported order PDF and email templates (within the `{items}` tag pair).

All other order details in the admin screen are correct (billing and shipping details, order total etc.)

I presume this is a bug?

EDIT: I forgot to mention, this applies to all orders - those in the system prior to updating to Store 2.0.5, and new orders placed after updating.

[image: Order details view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug introduced in Store 2.0.5. You can download the latest version 2.0.6 that was released today to fix this issue.

- [Full Release Notes](https://exp-resso.com/docs/release_notes.html#store_206)